# Akka HTTP how to POST singleRequest with Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I stuck with sending request with Akka HTTP `singleRequest()`. I'm trying to deal with Stripe API and it requires `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type for the incoming requests.

I tried to use following structure of HTTP request:

```
val authorization = Authorization(OAuth2BearerToken("some_token"))

Http().singleRequest(HttpRequest(
        uri = Uri("https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers"),
        method = HttpMethods.POST,
        headers = List(authorization),
        entity = FormData(Map("email" -> HttpEntity("test_1@email.com"))).toEntity(),
        protocol = HttpProtocols.`HTTP/1.1`)
      )
```

But in the Stripe logs I see following in the Parsed Request POST Body section:

(multipart form: 162)

So the question is how to set content type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was related to `FormData` type. In order to perform `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request you need to use `FromData` from package `akka.http.scaladsl.model`

So here is working example:

```
Http().singleRequest(HttpRequest(
        uri = Uri("https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers"),
        method = HttpMethods.POST,
        headers = List(authorization),
        entity = akka.http.scaladsl.model.FormData(Map("email" -> "user@email.com")).toEntity(HttpCharsets.`UTF-8`),
        protocol = HttpProtocols.`HTTP/1.1`)
      )
```